# how to build ios applications in ubuntu using Ionic Framework?

Tags: ios, angularjs, ionic-framework

Is there any way  to do it in Ubuntu Itself??

I have tried ...

```
$ ionic plaform add ios 


WARNING: Applications for platform ios can not be built on this OS - linux.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you need a Mac with Xcode to develop for iOS.

Edit: To be clear, you can not *build* your Ionic project for iOS on Ubuntu. However, You can of course develop on Ubuntu and use another machine for the actual Xcode build process.

Comment: Thank You for your reply

Comment: You will face the following error: ```UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): xcodebuild was not found. Please install version 7.0.0 or greater from App Store```

Answer (score 13):

Actually using Ionic Framework you sort of can.

Let me explain, won't be able to build it locally in your PC, but Ionic does provide a packaging service called "**Native Builds**" where you upload your project to their servers and they handle that for you.

You can read more about it here: http://ionic.io/platform#packaging

Comment: That is a good point. It's not that convenient not to be able to test the app locally on an iPhone but it's still a way of getting it out there.

Comment: Yupp, it's not ideal, but sometimes you gotta work with whatever tools you have. I'm saving for a Mac Book tho, it makes things faster

Comment: it might be helpful

Answer (score 3):

Only in OS X, you can use `ionic platform add ios`. But if you just develop apps without native plugins support and want to verify whether UI is compatible or not, you could use `ionic serve --lab`. This command will show UI for android and IOS in your default browser.

Comment: @Gopinath Glad that can help you.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `ionic build ios` on Ubuntu.

But you can test your ionic app with the [ionic view application](http://view.ionic.io/) on your Apple device.

You should upload your ionic app with : `ionic upload`

Comment: ionic upload does not access Social sharing ,and  get pictures from device .... (Plugins Activities)

Answer (score 0):

You can try Virtual Box with mac OS (install xcode + shared folders), but get ready for 9 hell circles of installing